# I am having problem with resolution in Temple run 2 on my LG-Optimus L3 E400

Tags: screen-resolution, lg-optimus-l3

I am having problem with resolution in Temple Run 2 on my LG-Optimus L3 E400. The game runs smoothly but the resolution is so big that I cannot even see the character running.

Please help!

Comment: That device [has an extremely low res screen](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_optimus_l3_e400-4461.php) (both resolution size and PPI).  I don't think we can help you, you probably need to contact the developer and ask them to support smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust that in in-game options and if that doesn't work in settings in developer options there is something to adjust resolution (at least on the galaxy anyway)

Comment: Just because it appears on the Galaxy, clearly the OP does not have it as the question is tagged *lg-optimus-l3* and not to assume it applies across the board :)

Comment: Thats why i said that but it might use that set up too